# Reverse Number in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want Reverse Number: example:
Textbox1.Text = `2 14 21 22 34 44`

a deployment algorithm to do this. make

> Expected Output: All Combination possible Reverse.

```
2 41 21 22 34 44
2 14 12 22 34 44
2 14 21 22 43 44
2 14 21 22 34 44
2 41 12 22 34 44
2 41 12 22 43 44
and so on...
2 14 21 22 34 44
```

What I try: it works, but it does not carry all the possible combinations, as in the above model.

```
 Dim r As Integer
    Public Function Reverse(rn As Integer)
        Dim value As Integer
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        For Each strValue As String In TextBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            If Integer.TryParse(strValue.Trim, value) Then
                values.Add(value)
            End If
        Next
        Dim numbers = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim result As Integer
        While numbers > 0
            rn = numbers Mod 10
            result = result * 10 + rn
            numbers = numbers \ 10
        End While
        Reverse = result
    End Function
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox2.Text = Reverse(r & " ")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do the logical workflow (the pseudocode) first, then code it. Being able to write pseudocode is a very underappreciated programmer superpower and will help you during your whole career.

Comment: Are you allowed duplicates?  For example, 22 is the reverse of 22, so a simple algorithm would create duplicates, unless you include logic to avoid/eliminate them.  Otherwise, your pattern is very similar to binary counting.  00001, 00010, 00011, etc.  Think about how you could generate binary numbers and you will find your answer.

Comment: yes, just like in the example. is allowed duplicate, 22 will remain 22.

Comment: Are there negative numbers?  Does 10 reverse into "1" or "01"?  You basically need 2 For-Loops, `For i = 0 to values.count - 1 Dim output as New List(Of String) For j = 0 to values.Count - 1 if (i = j) Then YourReverseCode Else output.Add(values(j)) End If Next Next`

Comment: without being 0 learn. if it is 1, then it will be 1. without 0. answer please with the code to the question, I can give you +1 to the answer.

Comment: I edited the original post.